# Error message doesn't show when the textfield is empty and showed on hover over

Tags: javascript, extjs

The first one is working as excepted.I am trying to borrow the same idea to display the error msg when users try to attempt the usage of blank value. 
I have few text fields,I want to display an error message when the user clicks on the save button with required fields empty or leaves blank after clicking the cursor on that tab
and not entering anything in the textfield and going to next text field. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
//First  code snippet  working propely. 
this.nameField = new Ext.form.TextField({
    fieldLabel:getMsg('testXml','global.name')
  ,allowBlank:false
  ,cls:'c-form-field-required'
  ,name:'Name'   
  ,blankText: testQR.getMsg('testXml','address.nameV')
    ,maxLength:100
});
 
this.formPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    labelWidth: 100
    ,labelPad: 10
    ,labelAlign: 'right'
    ,bodyBorder: false
    ,trackResetOnLoad: true
    ,cls: 'testQR-form-panel'
    ,autoScroll: true
    ,defaults: {
 width: 200
 ,msgTarget: 'under'
 ,emptyClass: 'c-form-empty-field'
 ,invalidClass: 'c-form-invalid'
 ,validateOnBlur: true
 ,validationEvent: 'blur'
    }
    ,items:[
 this.avKeyField
 ,this.addrKeyField
 ,this.nameField
 ,this.addressCodeField]          
}); 

/*
Second code snippet is not working as accepted. 

But when I click on the text field and leave it blank the border of the text field becomes red, 
and when I hover over the text field an error message will pop out. */

 this.descriptionField = new Ext.form.TextField({
 fieldLabel: getMsg('testXml', 'description'),
 allowBlank: false,
 cls: 'c-form-field-required',
 name: 'description',
 blankText: testQR.getMsg('testXml', 'description.required'),
 maxLength: 50,
 id:"DescriptionDetails"
    });

this.testFormPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
                id: 'testItemPanels',
                trackResetOnLoad: true
                ,cls: 'testQR-form-panel'
                ,autoScroll: true
                ,defaults: {
                     msgTarget: 'under'
                     ,emptyClass: 'c-form-empty-field'
                     ,invalidClass: 'c-form-invalid'
                     ,validateOnBlur: true
                     ,validationEvent: 'blur'
                },
 border: false
      ,autoHeight: true
      ,bodyStyle: 'padding:1px 1px 1px 1px'
      ,layout:'table'
      ,layoutConfig:{
   columns: 3
      }
      ,defaults: {
   labelSeparator: '',
   //margins:'0 0 0 5',
   style: 'marginRight: 5px;',
   labelAlign: 'top',
   layout:'form',
   border: false,
   bodyStyle:'background:transparent'
      },

 items:
     [{
  items:[this.nameField]
  },
  {
      items:[this.descriptionField]
  }                                
     ]
            });
```

Comment: I do not have extra validation functions defined in my ext js file.

Answer (score 0):

Apply

```
validateOnChange:false and allowBlank:false
```

in every fields that are required and then do your

```
form.isValid()
```

on save button click handler. It will work. If it doesnt please provide a fiddle recreating the issue.

Comment: The Validation is working, but it is not working properly. The error msgs are coming on hover for the first time itself, before clicking on anything even save also. I added the logic which you gave. looks it is not working still. Please could help. @Harshit Shah

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle for this recreating the issue?

Comment: I am new to EXT JS coding. Pls ,could you let me know what is fiddle means? Is it view or save part of the code??